# How to add "Title field with link to Edit Menu" to a View using code-behind C#?

Tags: development, list-view, editing-menu

all

I am trying to attempt adding Title with Edit Menu in SharePoint 2013 through code-behind. However, I am unable to do so. Below is my syntax I am using:

```
StringCollection strViewFields = new StringCollection();
strViewFields.Add("Title");

list.Views.Add("Custom View", strViewFields, String.Empty,
                100, true, false, SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false);

list.Update();
```

However, the results is that Title field in my view is just a basic text! I want to have what is like in the default which has in the right-side an edit menu (triple dots it looks like). I've tried to look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx

And I tried to use the "LinkTitle" .. I've successfully used the "Edit" but it looks different, it has a pencil and paper image compared to the default.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the field LinkFileName? Basically you are looking for a field in the list that has the [ListItemMenu property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.listitemmenu.aspx) set to true and add that fields to your view. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!