# How to add column with Link to item with edit menu in view from code behind?

Tags: view, codebehind

I am creating a view from code behind. The view contains Title column for which I would like to be a link to open the list item and have a drop-down menu.

I know that this is done by setting `<FieldRef Name='Title' ListItemMenu='TRUE' />`, but how can I achieve the same thing from code behind?

Here is the code for creating a view:

```
private SPView CreateView(SPList list, string title, string[] columnDisplayNames)
{
    StringCollection columns;
    string columnInternalName;
    SPViewCollection views;
    SPView view;

    columns = new StringCollection();
    foreach (string columnDisplayName in columnDisplayNames)
    {
        columnInternalName = this.GetListColumnInternalName(list, columnDisplayName);
        columns.Add(columnInternalName);
    }

    views = list.Views;
    view = views.Add(title, columns, string.Empty, 30, true, true);
    view.Update();

    for (int i = views.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        views.Delete(views[i].ID);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Note:
The accepted answer in [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72022/how-to-add-title-field-with-link-to-edit-menu-to-a-view-using-code-behind-c) is false, as the `Title` field that has ListItemMenu is `LinkTitle` (internal name) and using that column throws an exception.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mention code. It is used to show Context menu in other column apart from `Title Column` in SharePoint List.

```
SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["Tasks"]; //Change the list name here
SPField field = list.Fields["Priority"]; //Change the column name here
field.ListItemMenu = true;
field.ListItemMenuAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

You can replace the column name with your column name.